# How to add spaces into a text file?

Tags: c++, file

I have a text file like this:

```
100,Nguyen Van A,2004
101,Tran Thi B,2004
102,Vo Van C,2005
103,Truong Thi D,2005
```

How can I add one blank space right after each "," into that file using C++?

I've tried using find() function but nothing worked.

```
svFile.open("list_student.txt");
    while (getline(svFile, line, ','))
    {
        if (line.find(",", 0) != string::npos)
            svFile << " ";
    }
```

Comment: Split the strings, build up new ones and write out a new temporary file, then swap the new file with the old and delete the file with the "old" content.

Comment: The simplest solution is probably to read character by character from the input file, and write them to a temporary output file. When you have read a comma, add an extra space to the output file. When done, close the files and rename the temporary output file as the original input file.

Comment: how can I know whether I reach ","? should I compare between 2 char or use find function? sorry I'm a complete newbie.

Comment: Please see my answer, it uses find, but keeps track of the new position based on the size of the string you are replacing with. Other wise you'll keep finding "," in ", "

Answer (score 0):

Two options, read and write the file character by character, or option 2, read the entire text file into a string and then perform your required changes and write the file back:

Option 1 (Character by Character):

```
 char ch;
 fstream fin("list_student.txt", fstream::in);
 fstream fout("list_student_result.txt", fstream::out);
 while (fin >> noskipws >> ch) {
    fout << ch;
    if (ch==',')
    {
        fout << ' ';
    }
 }
 fout.close();
```

Option 2 (Read/Write entire file):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main()
{

    // Read the entire file
    std::ifstream t("list_student.txt");
    std::stringstream buffer;
    buffer << t.rdbuf();

    std::string myString = buffer.str();
    size_t start = 0;
    int pos = 0;

    // Set your start character and replace with string here
    std::string comma(",");
    std::string replaceWith(", ");

    // Replace the comma "," with ", " (and a space)
    while ((pos = myString.find(comma, pos)) != std::string::npos) {
        myString.replace(pos, comma.length(), replaceWith);
        pos += replaceWith.length();
    }

    // Write the formatted text back to a file
    std::ofstream out("list_student_result.txt");
    out << myString;
    out.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Duyên, I've updated my answer to also show you how to do this by reading character by character.